# Why does these two async fetches blocks each other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sftp

Currently I'm trying to make two fetches at the beginning of the website loading process. I'm getting my data via sftp and if I'm fetching both endpoints alone its working. But if I'm trying to get both at the same time, my image is "forever" fetching in the network tab and does not show up. So it seems that they block each other, but I don't understand this, because they are working asynchronously?

This is my main Page, where the image should load:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`${URLS.apiUrl}/image/label`)
    .then(async (x) => {
      let resp = await x.json()
      if (resp !== undefined && resp.id === undefined && resp.data === undefined) {
        setNoImageAvailable(true)
        return
      }
      setImage(resp.data)
    })
}, [reRenderValue])
```

Now I made another component for a better overview, which is linked into my main page and uses a own `useEffect` (I already tried it with using both fetches in one `useEffect`, but that also does not work)

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`${URLS.apiUrl}/files/gaugeNames`)
    .then(async (v) => {
      try {
        let resp = (await v.json())
        setFilenames(resp)
      } catch {
        console.log('Could not parse response')
      }
    })
}, [reload])
```

As I already said, I'm using sftp to get my data from a ftp, that's the way i do it:

```
async getGaugeFiles(req, res, next){
  // res.json([]);
  //Connect FTP Client
  await SFTPClient.connect()
  //Get all Gauge files from host
  let fileList = (await SFTPClient.listFiles(environment.FTP_PATH_GAUGE))?.map(f => `gauge_${f.name}`)

  //Disconnect FTP Clients
  await SFTPClient.disconnect()

  return res.json(fileList)
}
```

I already checked the return and it return me the correct fileList, so its working well.

Now comes my problem, I'm getting also an error in my backend if my trying to fetch both routes. It says "Error downloading file {FILENAME}: Error: _get: No response from server" and it also tells me "ERR_GENERIC_CLIENT"
This comes through my last function, where I'm loading my files

```
async download(file, path) {
  try {
    return await this.client.get(`${path}/${file}`)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error downloading file ${file}:`, err)
    return null
  }
}
```

Comment: So the two `fetch` calls in the `useEffect` hooks are not working? What are the other two code snippets for? Or am I misunderstanding what is or isn't working? Please clarify more exactly the issue.

Comment: Both hooks are working, but the gaugeNames UseEffect where the data comes from the getGaugeFiles function is blocking the label UseEffect. In the network tab i can see that the label fetch is "pending" the whole time.

Comment: Is this an issue with the server then? Perhaps it isn't handling concurrent requests well?

Comment: But then it should also not work if im running a single one or? Im really not understand why it tells me Error: _get: No response from server when im trying to fetch with 2 routes

Comment: Try adding a `.catch` in each fetch. Maybe you're getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with a timer. With a timer of 1 Second im letting the first fetch through and after that i can fetch the other things. Not the best solution but currently the only one which is working.